# How to push specific branch to remote with go-git

Tags: git, go, go-git

**What is the canonical way to push specific single local branch to specific remote with `go-git`?**

I have a local repository checked out and opened with `go-git`

```
repo, err := git.PlainOpen("my-repo")
```

The repo has default `origin` remote.

I'm trying to sync contents of this repository to another remote `mirror`, so I'm adding the remote

```
repo.CreateRemote(&config.RemoteConfig{
                Name: "mirror",
                URLs: []string{"git@github.com:foo/mirror.git"},
            })
```

First I fetch repo contents from `origin`

```
err = remote.Fetch(&git.FetchOptions{
                RemoteName: "origin",
                Tags:       git.AllTags,
            })
```

... and do a discovery of all branches and tags of interest with `remote.List()`

Final step is pushing the branches to `mirror`, while rewriting branch names based on a map. E.g. `refs/remotes/origin/master` checked out as `refs/heads/master` should be pushed to `mirror` remote as `main`. Therefore I'm iterating over the branches and trying to push them one by one:

```
refSpec := config.RefSpec(fmt.Sprintf(
                "+%s:refs/remotes/mirror/%s",
                localBranch.Name().String(),
                // map branch names, e.g. master -> main
                mapBranch(remoteBranch.Name().Short()),
            ))
err = repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
                RemoteName: "mirror",
                Force:      true,
                RefSpecs:   []config.RefSpec{refSpec},
                Atomic:     true,
            })
```

But this results in `git.NoErrAlreadyUpToDate` and there's nothing happening on the `mirror` remote.

Comment: from my deep dive - https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/master/remote.go#L741 - `cmd.Old == cmd.New` - the hashes are equal and therefore push command is not added to the queue

Comment: what does `localBranch` refer to ? don't you want to push `refs/remotes/origin/*` to your mirror ?

Comment: That being said: I find it surprising that `git-go` does the check *locally* and chooses to not send what he seems "up to date". This may actually be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `refSpec`, when pushing single branch to a remote, should **NOT** be in format `+refs/heads/localBranchName:refs/remotes/remoteName/remoteBranchName` as indicate e.g. [here](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/af1efaa7dfb2a33de9c15597dd2cc65ea626cf35/config/refspec.go#L26):

```golang
// RefSpec is a mapping from local branches to remote references.
...
// eg.: "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
//
// https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec
type RefSpec string
```

but as

```golang
"+refs/heads/localBranchName:refs/heads/remoteBranchName"
```

instead. See [example](https://github.com/davidlukac-wisi/go-repo-sync/blob/65e3e305d7cf367813675a8d8afc4acd818b4feb/main.go#L252):

```golang
    refSpecStr := fmt.Sprintf(
        "+%s:refs/heads/%s",
        localBranch.Name().String(),
        mapBranch(remoteBranch.Name().Short()),
    )
    refSpec := config.RefSpec(refSpecStr)
    log.Infof("Pushing %s", refSpec)
    err = repo.Push(&git.PushOptions{
        RemoteName: "mirror",
        Force:      true,
        RefSpecs:   []config.RefSpec{refSpec},
        Atomic:     true,
    })
```